# Why can't I see the documents in a document set?

Tags: document-library, document-set, settings, bug

I have an existing document library with content types, to which I have added the generic "Document Set" content type.  I can create new document sets and upload docs to the document sets, but I can't see the documents on the document set page.  It says "Drag files here to upload", but I would expect to see the files that I have already uploaded.  If I create a view on the document library with setting "Show all items without folders", I can see the files, and I can also see them under the document set folder when viewing with Explorer.  If I create a brand new document library and add Document Set content type, everything works fine and I can see the files that I upload.  It's just this one Document Library where I am having a problem.  Is this an issue of settings that I could resolve, and does anyone know what settings would affect this, or should I approach this as a bug?  Of course, I would really like to avoid re-creating the library from scratch.

Comment: Check the view settings and compare with the view settings of the new library you created.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but I have made the view settings identical, and I have reduced the visible columns to just "Name" and "Created". I still have this problem

Comment: any form of custom branding on the site?

Comment: Document Sets will use the default library view, unless you explicitly define one for them. Check that the default view is not filtered to exclude documents.

Answer (score 1):

two possible causes

The view displayed on the documentset detail page contains a field that does not exists. Remove the field from the view

Second possible cause: 
A custom master page where the placeholder 'PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea' is set to hidden or removed from the master page.  Removing this placeholder from the masterpage results in a JavaScript null reference error because the element 'idParentFolderName' is not found on the page.

Leave the 'PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea' in the masterpage and leave it visible. You can encapsulate it with a `<div style="display:none"> .... </div>`.

Comment: Third possible cause: the default view is filtered to exclude documents. ;)

Answer (score 0):

We've also seen this problem. Are any of the fields you've defined to be added to the documents from the set required fields? If so, we found the documents were still checked out, so the uploader was the only one to see them.

You can tell this by adding the 'checked out to' field to the view.

We actually had to back off on required fields being propagated down to the documents, because the people who used these document sets couldn't deal with the checkin process.